# Writing to a custom field in PHP

Tags: entities

In Drupal 7, using the Field module, Field SQL Storage and Field UI I've created several custom user fields.  I can display them in PHP like this:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);
if ($items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'field_keys_available')) {
   $keys_remaining = $items[0]['value'];
```

The above example displays the custom keys_available field, a field we use to determine if the user is entitled to software license keys.  I need to decrement field_keys_available in the PHP that issues a license key to a user.  Can someone help with the syntax on this?  I've discovered fifty ways to generate white screens, but haven't landed on the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something as simple as

```
$account = user_load($GLOBALS['user']->uid);
$edit['field_keys_available'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'new value';
user_save($account, $edit);
```

The comments in the [`user_save()` docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) have some more details and examples.